# Getting notified when a phone call ends when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, phone-call, core-telephony

I know similar questions are asked but none of them helped.

**My Observation**

There are two cases: 1) When app is running and in the foreground, visible to the user 2) User presses home button and app moves to the background, not visible to the user. In case 1) when a phone call comes and end I get all the events with no problem. In case 2) I get no events, but when user opens the app, then I get all the events that has happened when app was in the background.

**My Question**

How can I get my code working even when app is in the background? Or, how can I move my app from background to foreground when those events happen?

**What I've tried**

I've tried enabling background fetch at Background Modes at Info.plist with an implementation of `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`. It had no effect.

Below is my code:

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    // some other code above

    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
    {
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *) [[(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
        MainViewController *vc = nc.viewControllers[0];
        [vc setCallState:call.callState];
    }
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
-(void)setCallState:(NSString *)callStateString
{
    if ([callStateString isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"call connected!");
    } else if ([callStateString isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing])
    {
        NSLog(@"call dialing!");
    } else if ([callStateString isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"call disconnected!");
    } else if ([callStateString isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
        NSLog(@"call incoming!");
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"unknown call state %@", callStateString);
    }
}
```

Comment: you found the solution? If so,can you post it?

Comment: No solution, but found a workaround. I played an .mp3 file as soon as my app launches. As long as that sound file is on, I get all the events.